# How to capture the WM_CONTEXTMENU message using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c#, winapi, setwindowshookex

I am creating an MindJet MindManager add-in, in which I want to get the location of a context menu so I can retrieve an element under it. I used Spy++ to watch the windows messages and I can see that the WM_COMMAND message is sent when the context menu item is clicked. I can even catch that event by setting up a windows hook.

```
private static int _hookID;
private const Int32 WH_GETMESSAGE = 3;
private const Int32 WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
private const Int32 WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B;
public delegate int HookProc(int code, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public void SetUpHook() 
{ 
    HookHandler = HookCallback;
    _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, HookHandler, IntPtr.Zero, 
    threadId: AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
}

public int HookCallback(int code, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    ... 
    var msg = (MSG)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSG)); 

    if (msg.message == WM_COMMAND)
    {
         // Do stuff here
    }
    if (msg.message == WM_CONTEXTMENU)
    {
         // I was hoping for this to get catch the context messaages
         // but unfortunately these messages don't seem to be getting 
         // hooked the same way WM_COMMAND messages are
    }
    ...
```

Why do these messages show up in Spy++ ?

Is there a different hook I need to set to catch WM_CONTEXTMENU?

Comment: What are you hoping to do in response to `WM_CONTEXTMENU`? It's just a notification to the app that it should display a menu. The menu doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I need to get the point information from the menu so I can find the item underneath it.  var topic = Host.ActiveDocument.GetObjectByPoint(x / zoom, y / zoom) as Topic; There is a little more to it but the fact remains that the API provides GetObjectByPoint

Comment: Oh I see, so all you want is the coordinates? The message hook should work I would have thought.

Comment: Maybe it should but for whatever reason it doesn't. It looks like the program has a selected property that is activated by right click prior to the menu selection so that should suffice for my needs but it would be nice to know what might be the issue. It seems that in order to get the WM_CONTEXTMENU I have to enable child threads in SPY++. I am not sure if this is a lead or not but maybe somehow related.

Comment: *DefWindowProc generates the WM_CONTEXTMENU message when it processes the WM_RBUTTONUP or WM_NCRBUTTONUP message or when the user types SHIFT+F10* - maybe the target app is handling `WM_RBUTTONUP` directly and not passing the message through to `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: Wrong hook, WM_CONTEXTMENU is a sent message and thus not delivered through GetMessage().  Use WH_CALLWNDPROC instead.  Do beware it is a canon to kill a mosquito, override WndProc() or use the MouseClick event instead.

Comment: I would use WndProc but the code I am hooking doesn't belong to me and it is a COM component.